# Is there a way, we can disable protected routes in Spartacus while accessing through SmartEdit?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

> Is there a way, we can disable [protected
> routes](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/early-login/) (showing
> the login page if not logged in) in Spartacus while accessing through
> SmartEdit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not supported by default in Spartacus. But you might try writing a customization for it.

##### Caveats

You should first analyze all consequences and model the security threats related to your requirement, then consider if you accept them e.g.:

- some feature pages (e.g. CPQ configurator) don’t work properly unless the user is logged in
- you might open a security hole (e.g. a malicious user might possibly simulate/prepend he’s in smart edit context, and he will be able to open your storefront’s pages which are restricted for logged-in users only)

#### Hints for writing a customization

You will need to overwrite the method
`ProtectedRoutesGuard.canActivate()` to always return `true` in case when you’re in the smart edit context.

And to check if you’re in the smart edit context, you might want to use the method `SmartEditLauncherService.isLaunchedInSmartEdit()`